# docker -v no more needed? and Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I've read tutorials about use docker:

```
docker run -it -p 9001:3000 -v $(pwd):/app simple-node-docker
```

but if i use:

```
docker run -it -p 9001:3000 simple-node-docker
```

it's working too? `-v` is not more needed? or is taking from the Dockerfile the line WORKDIR?

```
FROM node:9-slim
# WORKDIR specifies the directory our 
# application's code will live within
WORKDIR /app
```

another tutorials use `mkdir ./app` on the workfile, anothers don't, so WORKDIR is enough to docker create the folder automatically if does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to get application content into a Docker container.  Many Node tutorials I've seen confusingly do *both* of them.  You don't need `docker run -v`, provided you `docker build` your container when you make changes.

The first way is to copy a static copy of the application into the image.  You'd do this via a Dockerfile, typically looking something like this:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
# Install only dependencies now, to make rebuilds faster
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
# NB: node_modules is in .dockerignore so this doesn't overwrite
# the previous step
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

The resulting Docker image is self-contained: if you have just the image (maybe you `docker pull`ed it from a repository) you can run it, as you note, without any special `-v` option.  This path has the downside that you need to re-run `docker build` to recreate the image if you've made any changes.

The second way is to use `docker run -v` to inject the current source directory into the container.  For example:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \          # clean up after we're done
  -p 3000:3000 \  # publish a port
  -v $PWD:/app \  # mount current directory over /app
  -w /app \       # set default working directory
  node \          # image to run
  yarn start      # command to run
```

This path hides everything in the `/app` directory in the image and replaces it in the container with whatever you have in your current directory.  This requires you to have a built functional copy of the application's source tree available, and so it supports things like live reloading; helpful for development, not what you want for Docker in production.

Like I say, I've seen a lot of tutorials do *both* things:

```sh
# First build an image, populating /app in that image
docker build -t myimage .
# Now run it, hiding whatever was in /app
docker run --rm -p3000:3000 -v$PWD:/app myimage
```

You don't need the `-v` option, but you do need to manually rebuild things if your application changes.

```sh
$EDITOR src/file.js
yarn test
sudo docker build -t myimage .
sudo docker run --rm -p3000:3000 myimage
```

As I note here the `docker` commands require root-equivalent permission; but on the flip side the final `docker run` command is very close to what you'd run "for real" (maybe via Docker Compose or Kubernetes, but without requiring a copy of the application source).

Comment: so i can mount a folder from my host, so i can work with git , because in the container i cant, but in this case running the app will use node_modules from docker, and not from the host?